# Javascript sort method handling null values

Tags: javascript

I have a list of objects where I want to sort the objects based on a field I know I can use sort methods. When the comparing field have null values, sorting is not happening, how to fix this issue?

http://jsfiddle.net/mailtoshebin/kv8hp/

```
var arrOfObj = [
    {
        "Name": "Zak",
        "Age": 25
    },
    {
        "Name": "Adel",
        "Age": 38
    },
    {
        "Name": null,
        "Age": 38
    },
    {
        "Name": "Yori",
        "Age": 28
    }
];

sortArrOfObjectsByParam(arrOfObj, "Name");
alert("ASCENDING: " + arrOfObj[0].Name + ", " + arrOfObj[1].Name + ", " + arrOfObj[2].Name);

function sortArrOfObjectsByParam(arrToSort , strObjParamToSortBy  ) {
    if(sortAscending == undefined) sortAscending = true;  // default to true

    if(sortAscending) {
        arrToSort.sort(function (a, b) {

            return a[strObjParamToSortBy] > b[strObjParamToSortBy];
        });
    }
    else {
        arrToSort.sort(function (a, b) {
            return a[strObjParamToSortBy] < b[strObjParamToSortBy];
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

you can deal with the null values inside the comp func:

```
    arrToSort.sort(function (a, b) {
         if (a[strObjParamToSortBy]==null) return 1
         if (b[strObjParamToSortBy]==null) return 0
        return a[strObjParamToSortBy] > b[strObjParamToSortBy];
    });
```

Comment: can I get objects with null values at the end of the sorted list? Thanks.

Comment: Set the first condition to  `if(a[strObjParamToSortBy] == null) return -1; ` http://jsfiddle.net/kv8hp/2/

Comment: I am sorry but multiple null objects are not displaying in result  only one is coming   http://jsfiddle.net/mailtoshebin/kv8hp/3/

Comment: jsfiddle.net/nQkBj  is working fine but only one null object is showing inside result

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstand your question... I updated the fiddle to include two null values. I also changed the alert to include all of the elements in the array. Both null values appear at the end.